# Query to return 1 instance of a record with duplicates

Tags: sql, database

INFO: I am working with Microsoft SQL.
Ok the title is confusing but here is an example of the table I'm working with:

```
ID    Value    Signal    Read    Firmware    Date           Time
5     123      656       444       217       3/30/2009     11:00:00 AM
5     123      421       333       217       3/30/2009     04:00:00 PM
5     123      111       666       217       3/30/2009     05:00:00 PM
9     321      231       551       216       3/30/2009     09:00:00 AM
9     321      599       887       216       3/30/2009     09:30:00 AM
```

So I want the Query to return:

```
ID    Value    Signal    Read    Firmware    Date           Time
5     123      111       666       217       3/30/2009     05:00:00 PM
9     321      599       887       216       3/30/2009     09:30:00 AM
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Value, Signal, Read, Firmware, Date, Time FROM ....
```

But this returns all of the results. I have also tried SELECT TOP 1... but I couldn't get that to work. I know this is simple, but I'm confused on how to get this to display only 1 single unique row.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT id, value, MIN(Signal), MIN(Read), MIN(Firmware), MIN(Date), MIN(Time)
FROM
  ...
GROUP BY
  ID, Value
```

Answer (score 1):

The records **are** distinct, there are different `Signal`, `Read` and `Time` values. How would you expect the SQL server to guess which one you'd like?

Your example suggests that you're interested in the most recent record of a given `Id`. If that's true, this query should work for you:

```
SELECT table.*
FROM table
JOIN (SELECT Id, Date, MIN(Time) FROM Table GROUP BY Id, Date) AS selector
ON (table.Id = selector.Id AND table.Date = selector.Date and table.Time = selector.Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ID, Value, Signal, Read, Firmware, Date, Time
FROM
  ...
GROUP BY
  ID, Value
```

Comment: Error: Cannot group on fields selected with '*' And it doesn't work when I include the columns.

Comment: Well, that was just an example. You'll have to put the exact fields. Let me clarify that for you...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Value, Signal, Read, Firmware, Date, Time FROM table_name t1 WHERE t1.Id = (SELECT DISTINCT t2.Id FROM table_name t2)
```

Assuming that there is a check so that records with the same Id also have same Value

Comment: Error: At most one record can be returned by this subquery.

Answer (score 0):

use TOP 1 WITH TIES

Comment: do you have an example of this? I get error: select statement includes a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

Similar query (uses CROSS APPLY and correlated subquery w/ TOP WITH TIES):

```
SELECT

        a.CustodianAccountNum,

        a.AccountName,

        a.AccountName2,

        a.AccountName3,

        a.AccountStartDate,

        a.AccountClosedDate,

        a.TaxableFederal,

        a.TaxableState,

        qq.ValuationDate,

        qq.MarketValue,

        cg.ClientGroupGUID as ClientGUID,

        c.ClientGUID as EntityGUID,

        convert (bit, case when b.cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as IsDuplicate 



  FROM (

        SELECT      

              a.CustodianAccountNum,

              MIN(a.AccountID) as AccountID,

              count(*) as cnt

        FROM Accounts a



        WHERE

              a.AccountID in (SELECT AccountID from dbo.FnGetFilteredAccountIDs(@CurrentUserID)) -- apply permisssions

              and a.DeletedDate is null



        group by a.CustodianAccountNum

  ) b

  INNER JOIN Accounts a

  ON

        a.AccountID = b.AccountID



  INNER JOIN ClientAccounts ca

  ON

        a.AccountID = ca.AccountID

        and ca.DeletedDate is null

  INNER JOIN Clients c

  ON

        ca.ClientID = c.ClientID

        and c.DeletedDate is null



  INNER JOIN ClientGroups cg

  ON

        c.ClientGroupID = cg.ClientGroupID 

        and cg.DeletedDate is null

  CROSS APPLY 

  (

        SELECT 

              SUM(MarketValue) as MarketValue, 

              MIN(ValuationDate) as ValuationDate 

        FROM

              (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES arv.MarketValue, arv.ValuationDate 

              FROM AccountReturnValues arv 

              where 

                    arv.AccountId = a.AccountId 

                    and a.AccountClosedDate is null

              order by ValuationDate desc

              ) q

  ) qq
```