# SQL Query to return a specific value from duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server where there are customers with active and inactive cards. If a customer has only one card, then it should return one row. If the customer has multiple cards, then how am I going to return the row of the active card, but with the sum of amount in both cards?

Example:

```
----------------------------------------                   
  CUSTOMER  |  CARD |  AMOUNT |  STATUS            
----------------------------------------            
  JOHN DOE  |  101  |   100   |  1
  JOHN DOE  |  102  |   200   |  2
  JANE DOE  |  103  |   100   |  2
```

Desired output:

```
----------------------------------------                   
  CUSTOMER  |  CARD |  AMOUNT |  STATUS            
----------------------------------------            
  JOHN DOE  |  101  |   300   |  1
  JANE DOE  |  103  |   100   |  2
```

- Status = 1 means Active, Status = 2 means Inactive

I will only need 1 card, if the customer has multiple, I want to get just the active card, but I need the accumulated amount of all cards. In above table, I want to get the total amount of purchase of John in both cards (300) but, only returning the row of the active card (101).

I have tried the solution I found here but my requirement is a bit different because I have a condition for a value I want to return.

[Query to return 1 instance of a record with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715804/query-to-return-1-instance-of-a-record-with-duplicates)

[Get Unique Results in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740285/get-unique-results-in-a-query?lq=1)

[SQL query to return one single record for each unique value in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982932/sql-query-to-return-one-single-record-for-each-unique-value-in-a-column?lq=1)

[How to return a single transaction per customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016913/how-to-return-a-single-transaction-per-customer?lq=1)

With regards to the amount, I can just place the accumulated amount of both cards later by using the customer id, but what is important for me right now is to be able to return only the active card if the customer has multiple.

Here's the query I am working on:

```
select customer, card, sum(amount), min(active)
from transactions
group by customer, card, active
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a sub-query that returns each customer's lowest active value. Join with that result:

```
select customer, card, amount, active
from transactions t1
join (select customer, min(active) as active
      from transactions
      group by customer) t2
    on t1.customer = t2.customer and t1.active = t2.active
```

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table #t
(
CUSTOMER  varchar (100),
CARD  varchar (50),
AMOUNT  varchar (100),
STATUS int
)

insert into #t values ('JOHN DOE','101','100',1)
insert into #t values ('JOHN DOE','102','200',2)
insert into #t values ('JOHN DOE','103','300',2)
insert into #t values ('JOHN DOE','101','100',1)
```

**QUERY**
You create a stored pocedur like above:-

```
CREATE PROC RESULT
AS
BEGIN
Select SUM(CONVERT (INT,AMOUNT)) AS [TOTAL AMOUNT] from #t
Select distinct CUSTOMER,CARD,AMOUNT,STATUS from #t where STATUS=1
END
```

**OUTPUT**

```
EXEC RESULT

TOTAL AMOUNT
700

CUSTMER    CARD    AMOUNT STATUS
JOHN DUE   101      100    1
```