# Get Unique Results in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im sure this will be pretty simple for a t-sql guru.

I have the following result from a table

```
idMain  IdSecondary  TextValue
1       1            text1
1       2            text2
2       5            text3
2       6            text5
```

And I want to obtain the first occurence of the idMain only.

The result should be like this.

```
idMain  idSecondary  TextValue
1       1            text1
2       5            text3
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Found a similar case here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715804/query-to-return-1-instance-of-a-record-with-duplicates and it turned out to work like a charm. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Note that the solution suggested by the accepted answer might not work for you if you have a different `TextValue` for the same `idMain`, as shown in your example. Note the difference between that post, where the same `ID` always has the same `Value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to join with a sub query, as in the following example. This assumes that by "first" you mean the lowest `idSecondary`:

```
SELECT t.idMain, sub_t.minSecondary, t.textValue
FROM   your_table t
JOIN   (SELECT   idMain, MIN(idSecondary) minSecondary
        FROM     your_table
        GROUP BY idMain) sub_t ON (sub_t.idMain = t.idMain);
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you mean by "***first***".  Normally this word would imply datetime or clock ordering, but your table does not have a date or datetime field in it...

So you have to clarify what you mean by "first"

If you have not stored in the table some value that can tell the query processor how to order any two records to distinquish between whatever you mean by the "first" one from the other one, then you're out of luck....

assuming that you do have such a field, (let's say it's `IdSecondary` for the sake of an example - since your sample results look like that is the case), then what you need to do is

```
Select * From Table a
Where IdSecondary= (Select Min(IdSecondary)
                   From Table
                   Where idMain = a.idMain)
```